# I want to create a search filter in Spring Boot controller, that takes 6 paramas and param value may be null then how to write a Data JPA Query?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Like I have a page where data are showing like first name, middle name, last name, address, city, state, country, age, salary.

There are a filter implemented that have 4 fields like city, age, salary, state. now I have to made a controller in Spring boot that takes all 4 fields as input params and find data from database using Spring Data JPA.

But my problem is that I want to filter Data sometime by salary only, sometime by city, state, sometime with all 4 params.
So what will be controller code and JPA Repository query to do this filter process.

Please Help me
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can have one SQL as a `native query` in Spring data JPA `@Query(value=SQL_Statement, native=true)` , SQL statement must fetch records based on OR conditions ! Hope that is helpful, you can crawl internet for JPA implementations. Although , not a good approach I'd suggest as it will involve validations, filterations etc, better to fetch what is ensured to be returned !

Comment: Use the `JpaSpecificationExecutor` and use a `Specification` to build a `Criteria` query. That way you can factor in the dynamic bits.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use JPA Specification instead,
to know more on specification code here is my thread on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73947993/use-orderby-when-chaining-multiple-specifications/74037123#74037123)

If you want to stick with JPA then here's the query which can help you

```
where (:field1 is null or table.field1 = :field1) 
and (:field2 is null or table.field2 = :field2)
...
...
...
```

Explanation: The above code will check if the parameter is null, then return true otherwise compare with the column.

Answer (score 0):

test if your parameters are null :

```
"where (:name is null or name = :name) and (:city is null or city = :city)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify Query with below clause Where you can write query in Repository and in
where clause you can add conditions. So this will work as expected.

@Query(value = "SELECT user from User user WHERE ((:name IS NULL) OR (user.name = :name)) AND ((:city IS NULL) OR (user.city = :city)))

Answer (score -1):

```
   @Query("select new com.rainbow.customer.rainbowcustomerservice.user.model.profile.AgentProfileDto("
            + " a.id as agentId,a.firstName ,a.middleName, a.lastName,a.mobileNumber,a.emailId,a.gender,a.userName,"
            + " a.status,p.id as profileId, p.profileType, p.isAadhaarVerified, p.isPanVerified,"
            + " p.isSelfieVerified, p.status as profileStatus, p.isDefault, p.pincode, p.remarks, p.district.name as districtName, "
            + "p.createdAt, p.sales.userName as salesUser, p.rmUser) "
            + "from Agent a inner join AgentProfileV2 p on a.id=p.agent.id inner join Zone z on p.district.stateId.zoneId=z.id where "
            + "( :#{#search.name} is null or lower(a.fullName) like %:#{#search.name}%)" +
            " and (:#{#search.userName} is null or lower(a.userName) like %:#{#search.userName}%)" +
            " and (:#{#search.mobileNumber} is null or lower(a.mobileNumber) like %:#{#search.mobileNumber}%)" +
            " and (:#{#search.gender} is null or lower(a.gender) like %:#{#search.gender}%)" +
            " and (:#{#search.emailId} is null or lower(a.emailId) like %:#{#search.emailId}%)" +
            " and (:#{#search.status} is null or lower(a.status) like %:#{#search.status}%)" +
            " and (:#{#search.profileType} is null or lower(p.profileType) like %:#{#search.profileType}%)" +
            " and (:#{#search.profileStatus} is null or lower(p.status) like %:#{#search.profileStatus}%)"+
            " and (:#{#search.zoneId} is null or p.district.stateId.zoneId = :#{#search.zoneId})"
    +" and (:#{#search.stateId} is null or p.district.stateId.id = :#{#search.stateId})"
    +" and (:#{#search.districtId} is null or p.district.id = :#{#search.districtId})"
    +" and (:#{#search.salesUser} is null or lower(p.sales.userName) like %:#{#search.salesUser}%)"
           + " and (:#{#search.rmUser} is null or lower(p.rmUser) like %:#{#search.rmUser}%)")
    Page<AgentProfileDto> findAgent(ProfileSearchDto search, Pageable sort);
```